# how to avoid attribute's redundancy coming from a inheritance

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, attributes

say I have this example :

```
class A1
{
    private:
    string name;
}

class A
{
    private:
    A1* field;
}
class B1 : public A1
{
    private:
    int id;
}
class B : public A
{
    private:
    B1* field;
}
```

so in this case I would have in my B class:

1. id attribute from the B1 class
2. name attribute coming from the inheritance of the class A.
3. another name attribute coming form the inheritance of B1 class from the class A1.

So what should I do to avoid this redundancy ?

Comment: "Attribute" has special meaning in programming nowadays. Use "member" or "field" instead to avoid confusion.

Comment: The way it's written right now, B contains only two `field` members: One from its own definition, and another one from inherited from A (but that's private, so not actually accessible). Did you mean to derive B from both A and B1 perhaps?

Comment: And where exactly do you see redundancy? What could be safely eliminated?

Comment: If you think that there is a redundancy (which I do not see here), then it was probably a bad idea to inherit.  Public inheritance should be a is-a relation.

Comment: actually it's simple A contains A1 and B contains B1 and B is derived from A and  B1 is derived from A1 and so I'm afraid that I would have multiplied member ( B now contains "name" member twice ) or isn't it ?

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now. But the direct `field` member in B is just a pointer, not really a full object.

Comment: @Glolita: well, but this is a `name` of different `A1`s, there's no problem at all.

Comment: okay so if we take @Vlad example I see th situaion like this : when creating a DogTrainer object that would call a DogTrainer constructor then Person constructor which allocates an animal object and then DogTrainer will allocate a Dog object which allocates again a animal object, so you see where I see the redundancy ! so Correct Me If I'm Wrong

Comment: @Glolita: why redundancy? There are _indeed_ 2 different animals involved: the trainee and the trainer's pet, each of them may need to be constructed.

Comment: ah okay I got it now, but that wouldn't be a wasting memory code or something , I mean that wouldn't make my program take more time at compiling ??

Comment: @Glolita yes it'll use more memory but if a class declared that variables then it needs them! Imagine: in a `for` loop you declare a variable, it consumes memory but you **need** it so if you inherit from a class then you need almost all its implementation (if it's not the case maybe the base class has a wrong design and can be splitted).

Comment: @Glolita: the speed of compiling isn't important. About wasting memory: if a trainer has no domestic pet, you can just skip the constructor, and set the `housePet` pointer to `NULL`.

Comment: okay things are clearer now ,thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any redundancy here. Let's rename the classes into something more useful:

```
class Animal // A1
{
    private:
    string name;
}

class Person // A
{
    private:
    Animal* housePet;
}
class Dog : public Animal // B1
{
    private:
    int breedId;
}
class DogTrainer : public Person // B
{
    private:
    Dog* trainee;
}
```

You see, no field can be safely eliminated. The `trainee` is not the same as the `housePet`, each of them needs a separate `name`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you haven't any redundancy.

`B` class didn't inherit any member from its base classes because they have been declared as private (then visible and accessible only from within the class they are declared).

For example:

```
class A
{
 private:
  int _privateMember;

 protected:
  int _protectedMember;

 public:
  int _publicMember;
};

class B : public A
{
 void test()
 {
  // This doesn't work, this field is private to the class
  // where it has been declared (A)
  _privateMember = 1;

  // This works, a protected member is accessible inside the class
  // where it's declared and derived classes.
  _protectedMember = 1;

  // This works, a public member is always visible and accessible.
  _publicMember = 1;
 }
};

void test()
{
 A a;

 // This doesn't work, a private field isn't accessible outside the class
 // where it has been declared
 a._privateMember = 1;

 // This doesn't work, a protected member is accessible only inside the class
 // where it has been declared and its derived classes
 a._protectedMember = 1;

 // This works, a public member is always visible.
 a._publicMember = 1;
}
```

Things can be more complicated than this, you do not need to always use public inheritance, for example:

```
class C : protected A
{
};

void test()
{
 C c;

 // This doesn't work! Field is public for its class but C has inherited from A
 // in a protected way (so only derived classes know that it derives from A).
 c._publicMember = 1;
}
```

Moreover you can make all private members of a class visible to another class or function using the `friend` declaration:

```
class D
{
 private:
  int _privateMember;

 public:
  int _publicMember;

  friend class DFriend;
};

class DFriend
{
  void test()
  {
   D d;

   // This works, public members are accessible
   d._publicMember = 1;

   // This works too, this class is a friend of D
   d._privateMember = 1;
  }
};
```

That said remember that when you derive from a base class you say "*derived class* **is** of type *base class*". For example you have a base class to describe a planet with some properties (modeled for simplicity as public fields):

```
class Planet
{
 public:
  int Diameter;
};
```

Then suddenly you discover you have to make it more general and you add a more general base class called CelestialBody:

```
class CelestialBody
{
 public:
  bool canCapture(CelestialBody anotherBody)
  {
   // Some calculations
  }

 private:
  vector<CelestialBody> _capturedBodies;
};

class Planet : public CelestialBody
{
 public:
  int Diameter;
};
```

Now you **say** this:

- A celestial body is something that can *capture* another celestial body;
- A celestial body keeps a private list of captured bodies because they may change some of its properties.
- A planet **is** a celestial body.
- A planet has a public (integer) property to describe its diameter in Km.

Private members of `CelestialBody` aren't visible outside of it (kind of implementation details). World knows that a `Planet` is a `CelestialBody` (because of public inheritance) then everything was public in `CelestialBody` is public in `Planet` too.

If you do not want to *say* this then you shouldn't simply use inheritance. Take a look to this articles:

- [Composition and inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance): when to inherit from another object and when to include another object as field.
- [Incapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding): incapsulation of informations inside a class.

Comment: thanks @Adriano for all that explanation but I'll tell you what I have in mind when I see planet public inherit from CelestialBody : Planet now have public member called Diameter and also public methode canCapture() ALSO a private member called _capturedBodies. correct me if am wrong but to me public inheritance is taking it all !

Comment: Yes it has but it can't use inherited private members. It's not redundancy (if Planet IS a CelestialBody then everything that describes a CelestialBody is appropriate to describe a Planet too).

Comment: @Glolita, inheritance takes EVERYTHING. With visibility you can specify what is visible and what is not. Let me say that protected/private inheritance isn't so common (if a Planet is a CelestialBody why you should keep it secret with private inheritance?)